# How to get code of unicode character using Ruby 1.8.6?

Tags: ruby, encoding, ruby-1.8

If I add this to the beginning of my script:

```
$KCODE = 'UTF8'
require 'jcode'
```

then I can walk over every char of a word containing unicode characters. Imagine a word containing umlauts or something, and I iterate over them like this:

```
word.each_char do |c|
  # do something with c
end
```

If `c` is a unicode character and I print it's size, it will be 2 ( composed of 2 characters ). How can I get `c`'s code? Is there some formula I could use, or is there something in the std lib that can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be:

```
c.unpack('U*').first
```